# How to parse xml into JSON using angular.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

I am trying to parse XML in angular.js, but it is very time consuming. Is there any smarter and faster way available to parse XML in angular.js.

Comment: Use this [library](https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON).

Comment: You need to show your code if you are needing to see if there are ways to make it simpler, other than using external libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse the xml using DomParser in core javascript,but it time consuming so i suggest you to use jQuery XML to JSON Plugin download plugin from url https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

and use it following way

```
var ajaxRequest = $http.get(UrlForService);
ajaxRequest .success(function(data){
  $scope.list = $.xml2json(data); // parsing xml response into Json
});
```

and use the list variable in your template whatever way you want-